# How to parse a calendar week number in Go

Tags: go, time, iso8601, date-parsing

How can I turn a string containing the year and an iso week date into a time object?

This is how the string I have looks like: `2020-15`, where `2020` is the year and `15` is the iso week number. Ideally, I would like to get the first available timestamp of a week (Monday at midnight).

I read through the documentation of the `Parse()` method here https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse, but I cannot figure out how to come up with a layout string of the reference time where the week is taken into account.

Comment: That is not supported by the `time` package.

Comment: You should be able to draw something up yourself pretty quickly by creating a new `time.Time` on January 1 of the specified year; advancing it to whatever day you want to treat as your canonical start of the week; then adding (7 * weekNumber) days to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to draw something up yourself pretty quickly by creating a new time.Time on January 1 of the specified year; advancing it to whatever day you want to treat as your canonical start of the week; then adding (7 * weekNumber) days to it, for example:

```
t := time.Date(year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, location)
offset := (t.Weekday() + 7 - weekStart) % 7
t = t.Add(time.Duration(offset*24) * time.Hour)
t = t.Add(time.Duration((week-1)*7*24) * time.Hour)
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/EjUpnRZRE6T